# Error in creating shard cluster mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have followed the mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/deploy-shard-cluster/) to create a sharded cluster. I have created a config server replica set and shard replica set with 3 members each.Following is the procedure I followed as per the docs:

Step 1: Created config server replica set with 3 members:

`mongod --configsvr --replSet "myrepl" --dbpath <path1> --port 27019
 mongod --configsvr --replSet "myrepl" --dbpath <path2> --port 27020
 mongod --configsvr --replSet "myrepl" --dbpath <path3> --port 27021`

Step 2: Connected a mongo shell to one of the mongod instances:

`mongo --host localhost --port 27019`

Step 3: Initiated the replica set in the mongo shell created above:

`rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "myrepl",
    configsvr: true,
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27019" },
      { _id : 1, host : "localhost:27020" },
      { _id : 2, host : "localhost:270" }
    ]
  }
)`

Step 4: Created shard replica sets:

`mongod --shardsvr --replSet "shardrepl"  --dbpath <path1> --port 37019
 mongod --shardsvr --replSet "shardrepl"  --dbpath <path2> --port 37020
 mongod --shardsvr --replSet "shardrepl"  --dbpath <path3> --port 37021`

Step 5: Connected to one member of the replica set and initiated the replica set:

`mongo --host localhost --port 37019
 rs.initiate(
  {
    _id : "shardrepl",
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "localhost:37019" },
      { _id : 1, host : "localhost:37020" },
      { _id : 2, host : "localhost:37021" }
    ]
  }
)`

Everything is fine till here, the problem is in the next step:

Step 6: Connect mongos to sharded cluster:

`mongos --configdb "myrepl"/localhost:27019,localhost:27020`

Further it is stated to connect a mongo shell to this this mongos instance using 
`mongo --host <hostname> --port <port>` But it's not explicitly stated which host or port to use here. What host or port should I use here? And where should I execute the further commands to add shards?

Although I had a strong feeling this won't work (and it didn't :p), I tried executing `mongo --host localhost --port 27019` and executed `sh.addShard("localhost:37019")` ,it gave an error- "no such command addShard"

Kindly help me out here,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved now. What I did is to start the mongos at a specific port number,like:

`mongos --configdb "myrepl/localhost:27019,localhost:27020 --port 47019`

Then I connected a `mongo` instance to it:

`mongo --host localhost --port 47019`

Further I executed all the commands to add shards in this shell and it worked! Please correct me if I'm wrong